# How to add two separate GA accounts in one Drupal site

Tags: google-analytics

I have one Drupal site and I am using [google analytic module](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics) for add ing GA account? Now client want to add two separate accounts.

> UA-87XXX-XX
>
> UA-87YYY-YY

How can I add these two accounts?

Answer (score 1):

Go to /admin/config/system/googleanalytics > ADVANCED SETTINGS > CUSTOM JAVASCRIPT CODE > Code snippet (after)

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-Y', 'auto', {'name': 'foo'});
ga(function(foo) {
  foo.send('pageview');
});
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-Y', 'auto', {'name': 'bar'});
ga(function(bar) {
  bar.send('pageview');
});
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In drupal 8 with google-analytics v8.x-2.x, go to /admin/config/system/google-analytics > Advanced settings > Code snippet (after), and type this:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-Y', 'auto',{'name': 'WebProperty2'});
ga('send', 'pageview');
ga('WebProperty2.send', 'pageview');
```

```
Code 1: UA-XXXXXXXX-X
Code 2: UA-XXXXXXXX-Y
```